# Can new connection pooling with pymongo2.6 break up a query?

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, pymongo

The new pymongo2.6 allows breaking up processes across multiple threads. I find it very useful.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pymongo
connection = pymongo.MongoClient(max_pool_size=8)

def update(id):
  connection.update({"_id":id},{"$set":{"field":"blah_blah"}},upsert=True)

p = Pool(8)
p.map(update,list_of_ids)
```

This works well. I was wondering however if querying a collection can be broken up? I know the cursor object is already split up into chunks so is there anyway to use thread concurrency to speed up a query?

Something like...

```
list_of_ids = []

def get_ids(chunk_of_cursor):
  for i in chunk_of_cursor:
   list_of_ids.append(i['_id'])

p = Pool(8)
p.map(get_ids,connection.find({"field":"somecriteria"})
```

Anyway to pass the cursor object as chunks to a function.

J

Answer (score 2):

If you mean using skip and limit with multiple cursors to speed up querying, unfortunately, the answer is probably not. Take, for example, if you wanted to return 1000 results in 10 chunks, and thread 10 cursors to each return 100 of the results. Due to the way skip is implemented on the server side, the overhead for each cursor skipping ahead would probably outweigh the benefits of the pooling.

However, I'm not sure what you're referring to with regards to the new implementation of max_pool_size-- it's just a hard cap on connection count. Pymongo has no particular features to support breaking up processes across multiple threads.